# Padronizar edtitext tipo date

Tags: android, xml, calendar, datapicker

Gostaria de saber como eu altero o formato do `EditText` tipo date

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"        
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/dtfinal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="@string/lbldtfinal"/>
```

Com esse formato, quando o usuário digita a data, o formato que aparece na tela e e salvo para meu programa é: 14042016. Gostaria que, quando o usuário fosse digitar a data, automaticamente fosse sendo acrescentado (-), ou seja, quando ele digitar o dia 14, aparecesse na tela para ele 14- e ai o resultado do que ele digitou ficaria 14-04-2016.
Sei que tem que alterar algo no `xml`, e sei tbm que existe o `calendar` e o `datapicker`,  mas eu gostaria de algo mais simples como esse exemplo acima.
Mas exemplos com datapicker seria bom para futuras alterações, desde que explicado como devo usá-lo.

Comment: Tiago, dá uma olhada nessa lib: [Masked-Edittext](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3033)